# Leetcode problem number 20, "Valid Parenthesis" gives different outputs depending on IDE/Editor

Tags: python

When I run this program in PyCharm and Replit it gives me the right answers. However, when I run it in LeetCode, the program does not pass the tests and in fact gives me the opposite answers. Why is this?

This is the code that I have tried:

```
class Solution:
  def isValid(self, s: str) -> bool:
    s2=sorted(s)
    s1 = str(s2)[1:-1]
    count = 0
    extcount=0
    for i in range (len(s1)):
        if s1[i] == '(':
            count += 1.3
        elif s1[i] == '[':
            count += 2.7
        elif s1[i]=='{':
            count += 3.1
        elif s1[i] == ')':
            count -= 1.3
        elif s1[i] == ']':
            count -= 2.7
        elif s1[i]== '}':
            count -= 3.1
        else:
            pass
    if count==0:
        extcount+=1
        x=bool(extcount)
        print(x)
    else: 
        print (bool(extcount))
```

Comment: What is the problem you're solving? What should it do? What does it do instead?

Comment: You should `return` your answer and not `print` on Leetcode.

Comment: Don't use floating point numbers for this, they might not be 100% accurate.  Use integers.

Comment: @MarkRansom Which integers would you suggest?

Comment: @MarkRansom If you were thinking of for example 13, 27, 31, that doesn't work. Leads to incorrectly computing that `"((([[}}}"` is valid.

Comment: @KellyBundy I was thinking any 3 coprime numbers would work, and 13, 27, 31 qualify.  But I didn't want to waste the time studying the algorithm in enough detail to know if it would work.  Thanks for proving it didn't, to me that indicates a flawed algorithm.  Regardless my advice about avoiding floating point still stands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach to solving [Valid Parentheses](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-parentheses/) won't work because sorting the string breaks the original order, making it impossible to validate balanced parentheses.

Consider the string `s = "([)]"`. This string is not a set of valid parentheses, but let's see what happens when you sort it.

Sorted s: `s2 = "()[]"`

Your count-based method would incorrectly identify this as balanced because you have one of each type of parenthesis, and your count would end up being zero. However, the original string s was not balanced due to the ordering: the brackets don't close in the last-in, first-out (LIFO) order.

So, sorting breaks the spatial relationship needed to validate the sequence, making it an incorrect approach for this problem.

---

Instead try using a [Stack](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(data_structure)) to solve this problem:

```py
class Solution:
    def isValid(self, s: str) -> bool:
        closing_by_opening = {'(': ')', '{': '}', '[': ']'}
        stack = []
        for c in s:
            if c in closing_by_opening:
                stack.append(c)
            else:
                if not stack or closing_by_opening[stack.pop()] != c:
                    return False
        return not stack
```